# Cmd + Opt + F stopped working

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should allow me to access the search box in many applications. It doesn't anymore though.

I have Karabiner running, but haven't specifically done anything with that combination. Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is assigned. When watching the keyboard events in the EventViewer, that comes with Karabiner, pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> doesn't register at all.

I remember that is has been working on and off before. Can't pin that down though. The global keyboard shortcut overview in the preferences doesn't show any action assigned to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

I am on El Capitan 10.11.6

What could be the issue? How can I further debug this?

Comment: I agree that Cmd + F is the standard search shortcut. But some applications, like Evernote, allow search on different levels. In the case of Evernote a search within the current node (Cmd + F) and a search for a note (Cmd + Opt + F). I wasn't clear on the Eventviewer thing. I do not have any other issues with the F key, only when Cmd and Opt are already pressed

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that there is an interdependence between key states and events on the hardware level? From all I know about this stuff, that's all worked out in the OS and the keyboard only sends KeyUp and KeyDown events. If it's the keyboard, I'll have to face that, but I just don't see a high chance that it is. I'll switch off Karabiner and see what happens...

Comment: True, I accidentially mispresented that in my OP. In my comment I added "I wasn't clear on the Eventviewer thing. I do not have any other issues with the F key, only when Cmd and Opt are already pressed". I'll switch it all off, test with Key Codes and report. Thx

Comment: I switched off Karabiner and Keyboard Maestro. Makes no difference. Neither EventViewer nor Key Codes shows the firing of the F key when Cmd + Opt are pressed. I tried with all other modifier combinations and they work. And I looked through the global keyboard shortcuts in the settings again. Cmd + Opt + F is not used. But when I try to assign that combination as a global hotkey to some function it does work! That finally rules out the hardware issue :-)

Comment: I still have the problem. What can I do? P.S.: It look like I am talking to myself above, but there were comments from another user, that he must have deleted. God knows why...

Comment: I would [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/252498/edit) your question to clarify exactly what you're asking (drawing on your comments above to provide a clearer picture *within* your question). It would also be good to include at least one application you know that normally works with the `Opt + Cmd + F` shortcut so that the community has something to work off/compare with. This is important because within macOS the `Opt + Cmd + F` shortcut *usually* works to go to the search field, so we need to eliminate the possibility that it's not actually doing something you just don't expect.